# Inverse Laplace transformation of a rational function

Tags: inverse-laplace

I just don't seem to be able to crack this inverse Laplace:

$$
\mathcal{L}^{-1} \left\{ \frac{20000s}{s^2 + 20000s + 5\cdot 10^8} \right\} (t).
$$

Could someone help me out? I'm totally lost. I don't seem to be able to partial fraction decompose it, so I don't know where to start.

Comment: Please avoid ["I have no clue"](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933) questions.

Comment: "I don't seem to be able to partial fraction decompose it" you already know how to start: you could try to find the partial fraction decomposition of it first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Noting
$$ s^2+20000s+5\cdot 10^8=(s+10000)^2+20000^2 $$
one has
$$ L^{-1}\bigg(\frac{20000s}{s^2+20000s+5\cdot 10^8}\bigg)=L^{-1}\bigg(\frac{20000(s+10000)-2\cdot10000^2}{(s+10000)^2+20000^2}\bigg)=20000e^{-10000t}\cos(20000t)-10000e^{-10000t}\sin(20000t). $$
Here
$$ L^{-1}\bigg(\frac{s-a}{(s-a)^2+b^2}\bigg)=e^{at}\cos(bt), L^{-1}\bigg(\frac{b}{(s-a)^2+b^2}\bigg)=e^{at}\sin(bt).$$

Comment: I post the following to ensure you cannot claim ignorance in the future:  Please read thoroughly, [Enforcement of Quality Standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards).  Having done this, users can now flag ongoing occurrences of further answers from you to very low quality questions, if the pattern continues, for moderator attention, along with a link to this comment.  Please do not answer low quality questions.

Answer (score 1):

Hint

$(s+10000-20000i)(s+10000+20000i)=s^2+20000s+5\cdot 10^8$